# Hibernate query from two entities which are extended same entity

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm

According to my design, i have created entities which extend the same entity. But some entities have additional attributes (columns).

My problem is the following: When i call a query for each entity there is no problem. But when calling more tables in one query, there is trouble with.

This query works well: QueryA

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from ExtendedA where title like :title order by pubdate desc ");
```

But this fails ! **QueryB**

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from ExtendedA, ExtendedB where title like :title order by pubdate desc ");
```

There is no problem if i call just this; QueryC

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from ExtendedA, ExtendedB");
```

The problem is when using ordering or (where-)clauses.

ExtendedA and ExtendedB are inherited from classA which has `pubdate, title` and other attributes. In that case each classes should have these attributes. Calling them one-by-one, there is no problem with these attributes (columns).

Can anyone help me to write a query like **QueryB**.,

Thanks.

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not extract ResultSet

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2399)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    project.data.dao.general.top.AnnouncementDAOImpl.getAll(AnnouncementDAOImpl.java:47)
    project.data.service.general.top.AnnouncementServiceImpl.getAll(AnnouncementServiceImpl.java:51)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.getAll(Unknown Source)
    project.endpoint.general.top.AnnouncementEP.getAll(AnnouncementEP.java:35)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'pubdate' in order clause is ambiguous
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:93)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2399)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    project.data.dao.general.top.AnnouncementDAOImpl.getAll(AnnouncementDAOImpl.java:47)
    project.data.service.general.top.AnnouncementServiceImpl.getAll(AnnouncementServiceImpl.java:51)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.getAll(Unknown Source)
    project.endpoint.general.top.AnnouncementEP.getAll(AnnouncementEP.java:35)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
```

Comment: StackTrace please? But i suppose you need to use table aliases.

Answer (score 2):

As far as you're using entities with the same attribute names its not clear which of entity's attributes should be used. For example, are you ordering by ExtendedA.pubdate or ExtendedB.pubdate?

You have to specify how the attributes and entities correspond to each other. Like

```
Query query = session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from ExtendedA as a, ExtendedB as b where a.title like :title and b.title like :title order by a.pubdate desc ");
```

Comment: is there a way order by just pubdate. Because both of them have

Comment: From Hibernate's point of view you're using two different tables with two different set of columns but having the same name. As a result you'll have double count of columns, so you'll have to order by each of them. In your case it better to mark your superclass as entity and make JOINED inheritance for subclasses. In such case you'll have all the common data stored in your superclass table, so you'll be able to select/orderby from it. And then you can join particular data from ExtendedA, ExtendedB using inner joins.